# Помогите пожалуйста исправить проблему в коде C#

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Practica
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string Family = Convert.ToString(this.textBox2.Text);
                int TouristID = int.Parse(this.textBox1.Text);
                conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Practica; AttachDbFilename = " + @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Practica.mdf" + "; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");

                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand myCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
                myCommand.CommandText =
                "UPDATE Туристы SET Фамилия = @Family WHERE [Код туриста] = @TouristID";
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Family", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                myCommand.Parameters["@Family"].Value = Family;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TouristID", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
                myCommand.Parameters["@TouristID"].Value = TouristID;
                int UspeshnoeIzmenenie = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (UspeshnoeIzmenenie != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Изменения внесены", "Изменение записи");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Не удалось внести изменения", "Изменение записи");
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }


    }

        private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int TouristID = int.Parse(this.textBox3.Text);
                string Family = Convert.ToString(this.textBox4.Text);
                string FirstName = Convert.ToString(this.textBox5.Text);
                string MiddleName = Convert.ToString(this.textBox6.Text);
                conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Practica; AttachDbFilename = " + @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Practica.mdf" + "; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
                myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " +
                "Туристы ([Код туриста], Фамилия, Имя, Отчество) " +
                "VALUES (@TouristID, @Family, @FirstName, @MiddleName)";
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TouristID", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
                myCommand.Parameters["@TouristID"].Value = TouristID;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Family", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                myCommand.Parameters["@Family"].Value = Family;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                myCommand.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = FirstName;
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@MiddleName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                myCommand.Parameters["@MiddleName"].Value = MiddleName;
                int UspeshnoeIzmenenie = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (UspeshnoeIzmenenie != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Изменения внесены", "Изменение записи");
                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Не удалось внести изменения", "Изменение записи");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int TouristID = int.Parse(this.textBox7.Text);
                conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = Practica; AttachDbFilename = " + @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Practica.mdf" + "; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand myCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
                myCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Туристы" +
                "WHERE [Код туриста] = @TouristID";
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("@TouristID", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
                myCommand.Parameters["@TouristID"].Value = TouristID;
                int UspeshnoeIzmenenie = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (UspeshnoeIzmenenie != 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Изменения внесены", "Изменение записи");
                }
                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Не удалось внести изменения", "Изменение записи");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка возникает до того, как `conn = new SqlConnection`, поэтому `conn` остаётся равным `null`, отсюда и NRE в блоке `finally`

Answer (score 1):

Вы два раза выполняете  `conn.Close();` 
Первый раз внутри конструкции `try{..тут..} catch{..}`, а второй раз в `finally`, но т.к вы раньше уже закрыли, то в `finally` закрывать уже нечего, вот и ошибку дает.

Если вы не знали, то блок `finally` в любом случае выполнится, это надо учитывать

п.с можете везде изменить на такую конструкцию `conn?.Close();`, что соответствует

`if (conn != null) conn.Close();`

Comment: А можно подробнее рассказать или показать на примере,как это исправить,а то просто C# начала только недавно изучать

Comment: @Катерина на какой кнопке дает такую ошибку ? мой ответ подходит под кнопку `btnUpdate`

Comment: Ошибку выдает на btnDelete до нее все работает,как надо

Comment: @Катерина как подметил Андрей NOP, ошибка возникает до присваивания значения `con`, скорее всего на присваивании `TouristID`, в результате чего `con` остается равным `null`, выполняется блок `catch`, а после него блок `finally`. Дополнил ответ, проверяйте на `null`, прежде чем закрывать

Comment: Все,разобралась,пробела не хватало перед WHERE myCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Туристы" +
                " WHERE [Код туриста] = @TouristID";

Comment: @Катерина это хорошо, но замечания, что я привел в ответе так же важны, это позволит избежать возможного краша